# I want to return the string that has the highest sum in an array for Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

So far I am able to return the sums of the strings:

```
puts "Please enter strings of #'s to find the number that has the greatest sum."
puts "Use commas to separate #'s."
user_input = gets.chomp
array = user_input.split(",")
array.map do |num_string|
  num_string.chars.map(&:to_i).inject(:+)
end
```

But I wish to return the string that adds up to the highest value. For instance: If I have array = ["123","324","644"] I need it to return the sums of each value so the result should be 6,9,and 14 respectively. Since 1+2+3=6 etc. I am this far but now I need to return "644" as the answer since it is the string that sums to the highest value.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by):

```
arr = ["123","324","644"]

arr.max_by { |s| s.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,c| t+c.to_i } }
  #=> "644"
```

Let's see how this works.  [Enumerable#max_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) computes a value for each element of `arr` and returns the element of `arr` whose computed value is greatest. The calculation of the value for each element is done by `max_by`'s block.

```
enum0 = arr.max_by
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["123", "324", "644"]:max_by>
```

You can see the three elements of this enumerator. Sometimes it's not so obvious, but you can always see what they are by converting the enumerator to an array:

```
enum0.to_a
  #=> ["123", "324", "644"]
```

Elements of `enum0` are passed to the block by the method [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) (which in turn calls [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each)). You would find that:

```
enum0.each { |s| s.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,c| t+c.to_i } }
```

returns `"644"`.

The first element of the enumerator (`"123"`) is passed to the block by `each` and assigned to the block variable `s`. We can simulate that with the method [Enumerator#next](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-next):

```
s = enum0.next
  #=> "123"
```

Within the block we have another enumerator:

```
enum1 = s.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "123":each_char> 
enum1.to_a
  #=> ["1", "2", "3"]
enum1.reduce(0) { |t,c| t+c.to_i }
  #=> 6
```

This last statement is equivalent to:

```
0            #  initial value of t
0 + "1".to_i #=> 1 (new value of t)
1 + "2".to_i #=> 3 (new value of t)
3 + "3".to_i #=> 6 (new value of t)
```

`6` is then returned by `reduce`.

For the next element of `enum0`:

```
s = enum0.next
  #=> "324"
s.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,c| t+c.to_i }
  #=> 9
```

and for the last element `enum0`:

```
s = enum0.next
  #=> "644"
s.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,c| t+c.to_i }
  #=> 14
```

Since `14` is the largest integer in `[6, 9, 14]`, `max_by` returns the last element of `arr`, `"644"`.

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you! Could you perhaps give a brief explanation of what's going on in this function?

Comment: This is perfect. Great explanation, really helped me grasp it.

Answer (score 2):

```
yourArray = ["123","324","644"]
highest = -1
pos = -1
yourArray.each_with_index{ |str, i| 
  sum = str.split("").map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
  highest = [highest,sum].max
  pos = i if highest == sum
}
puts "highest value is " + yourArray[pos]
```

lets look at each step, map lets us enumerate the array and returns a new array with whatever we return from map:

```
yourArray.map{ |str| ... }
```

Here we're taking our strings in the array and splitting them into arrays of ["1","2","3"] for example, then the `to_i` portion converts this to an array such as [1,2,3] then finally reduce gives us our sum:

```
sum = str.split("").map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)
```

Here we're keeping track throughout the loop of the highest sum we've seen so far:

```
highest = [highest,sum].max
```

If ever the current sum is the highest, store its position in the array

```
pos = i if highest = sum
```

finally, use the stored array position to print out whatever exists there in the original array (the positions line up):

```
puts "highest value is " + yourArray[pos]
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I understand the explanation but when i run it throughout the emulator and change the values it always returns the final value. Not the value with the largest sum. Did we perhaps miss a step?

Comment: the if should have == not =

Comment: hey @ebfd there was a typo (= instead of ==)